# I want to downsample my input node to 8000 Sample rate with AVFoundation

Tags: ios, swift3, avfoundation, audioformat

I have the following code to try with the sample rate 8000
how can i down sample the sample rate ? 
i find a solution but it doesn't work for me!

and this is the solution....

```
    assert(audioEngine.inputNode != nil)
    let input = audioEngine.inputNode!

    let audioFormat = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32, sampleRate: 8000, channels: 1, interleaved: false)
    let mixer = AVAudioMixerNode()
   // var mainMixerNode: AVAudioMixerNode { get }
    audioEngine.attach(mixer)
    audioEngine.connect(input, to: mixer, format: input.inputFormat(forBus: 0))
    mixer.volume = 0

    audioEngine.connect(mixer, to: audioEngine.mainMixerNode, format: audioFormat)

    do {
        try audioEngine.start()

        mixer.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: audioFormat, block: {
            (buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer!, time: AVAudioTime!) -> Void in
            //some code here
            print(buffer)

            let firstChannel = buffer.floatChannelData?[0]

            //UnsafeMutablePointer
            let arr = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: firstChannel, count: Int(buffer.frameLength)))

            self.array.append(contentsOf: arr)

            print(self.array)


        })

    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

But in my self.array is always null = 0

what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Where do you create `self.array`? It's probably just not initialized.

Comment: init() {
        array = [Float]()
    }
I create it in my init() function. 
after i created it   var array : [Float]

Comment: I'm facing this same problem - did you manage to solve it?

Comment: i have code it in objective-c with AudioToolbox. WIth AVFoundation i dont find any Solution.